# Not printing the proper value

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I'm trying to do some **string.find** magic between data out off a XML file and **check1/2/3** but when i **print(""..input)** it prints **Feb 12 20:38:39.410: check1** and not **jan**

```
check1 = 'jan'
check2 = 'kevin'
check3 = 'rob'

inputNumber = 1
input = 'check' .. inputNumber

print(""..input)

inputNumber = inputNumber + 1
```

Not quite sure what i'm doing wrong here, please give me some advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The script prints the proper value, just not what you expect. To print the value you want you need to access it as a field in the global table:

```
input = _G['check' .. inputNumber] -- instead of: 'check' .. inputNumber
```

This prints `jan`. See Programming in Lua on [Accessing Global Variables with Dynamic Names](http://www.lua.org/pil/14.1.html).